# PHP, Codeception, Firefox and new tab - how to?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, codeception

I have a test for PHP project which opens a new tab by double-click. I test it in Firefox.

I am new to Codeception, but I've read and tried everything I've found with no luck.

I have a table which rows are spans. I want to double-click it and to check if correct page is open.

I try:

```
        $i->scrollTo(['xpath' => '//span[text()="test"]']);
        $i->doubleClick(['xpath' => '//span[text()="test"]']);

        $i->waitForText("test text", 15);
        $i->seeCurrentUrlMatches('~^/register/materials/view/\d+$~');
```

The issue is that doubleClick opens a requested page in new tab like this:

```
jumpTo: function(row) {
                            const link = document.createElement('a');
                            link.href = window.location.pathname + '/view/' + row.id;
                            link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                            document.body.appendChild(link);
                            link.click();
                    },
```

If I try to run this test as is - it starts, double-clicks span, then new tab opens, focus switches to it, I see correct page and test text on it, but test fails because it does not see requested text because it seems that though I see that tab changed the WebDriver remains on first tab.

I tried switchToNextTab() - it does not work. Sometimes switchToNextTab() 3 times in a row works, sometimes not.
I tried reloadPage() - it reloads first tab, not the one recently opened.
I tried

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function (\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver) {
    $handles=$webdriver->window_handles();
    $last_window = end($handles);
    $webdriver->focusWindow($last_window);
});
```

and it seems that there is one currently active window in terms of this method ($handles is an array of 1 element).

I tried closeTab() - it closes entire Firefox instance.

How can I programmatically change active tab?